# Histogram in MATLAB 2014

Tags: matlab, histogram

Anybody know how to use histogram (not hist) function in MATLAB 2014?

I read a MATLAB documentation that there is

```
histogram(X)
histogram(X,nbins)
histogram(X,edges)
```

Thank you for your help

[histogram function in MATLAB Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#zmw57dd0e340688)

Comment: yeah, you use it exactly as you put there. What is the question?

Comment: There are 2 MATLAB versions per year. Do you have R2014a or R2014b? `histogram` was introduced in R2014b. `hist` is the function for earlier versions of MATLAB, why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html?refresh=true .

As noted, this was introduced in R2014b. The version command will show you what version you are running (R2014a or R2014b).

Answer (score -1):

the documentation have example use it, 
but in 2014a it is a simulink block,

*Histogram
Generate histogram of input or sequence of inputs
    The Histogram block computes the frequency distribution of the elements in the input. You must use the Find the histogram over parameter to specify whether the block computes the histogram for Each column of the input or of the Entire input. The Running histogram check box allows you to select between basic operation and running operation, as described below.

The block distributes the elements of the input into the number of discrete bins specified by the Number of bins parameter, n.

```
y = hist(u,n)                   % Equivalent MATLAB code*
```